# How to select nested elements with encodeURIComponent()?

Tags: jquery, nested, traversal, element, encodeuricomponent

Just a quick question with something that is wracking my brain. I cant get the encodeURIComponent to select nested elements, specifically,

```
encodeURIComponent($(".signs selected_sign > #s2FaceFinish").val());
```

just produces an 'undefined value" - /online-order2.html?size=1cm%20x%20&width=2cmundefined:

```
$(function () {
      $("#proceed_button").bind("click", function () {
        var url = "online-order2.html?size="
        + encodeURIComponent($("#height").val())
        + "cm x " + "&width=" 
        + encodeURIComponent($("#width").val()) + "cm" 
        + encodeURIComponent($(".signs selected_sign > #s2FaceFinish").val());
        window.location.href = url;
    });
  });
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<article>
  <form action="" id="sDimensions" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div class="height">
      <input id="height" type="number" maxlength="3" name="SignHeight" value="" />cm height<br>
    </div>
    <div class="width">
      <input id="width" type="number" maxlength="3" name="SignWidth" value="" />cm width<br>
    </div>
  </form>
</article>


<article class="signs selected_sign">
  <form id="s2Options">
    <div class="sign_options>"Face finish: "
      <select name="s2FaceFinish" id="s2FaceFinish">
        <option value="printed">Printed</option>
        <option value="vinyl">vinyl</option>
      </selected>
    </div?
  </form>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit, updated

`selected_sign` within selector `$(".signs selected_sign > #s2FaceFinish").val()` 
invalid selector (`html` not appear to contain `selected_sign` element / tag) ?

At below changed to

```
$(".signs .sign_options > #s2FaceFinish").val()
```

---

Note, Spaces within `"cm x "` not being encoded in `url` string

Try

```
$(function () {
      $("#proceed_button").bind("click", function () {
         var url = "online-order2.html?size="
        + encodeURIComponent($("#height").val() + "cm x ")
        + "&width=" 
        + encodeURIComponent($("#width").val()) + "cm" 
        + encodeURIComponent($(".signs .sign_options > #s2FaceFinish").val());
        console.log(url);
      });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/kwqoyt0j/

Comment: Noted, thanks! But still need to know how to get encodeURIComponent to get value of #s2FaceFinish in .signs selected_sign...

Comment: Tried piece ? Still get error ? If possible , can post `html` / `.val()` of selected elements ?

Comment: I've added the HTML on which the Jquery 'encodeURIComponent' tries to extract the s2FaceFinish value but returns 'undefined'

Comment: `#height` and `#width` elements / values ?

Comment: Added form of how I get height & width.

Comment: Hi  guest271314, your example works, but basically, "signs selected_sign" has to be the handle by which I get hold of the subelement s2FaceFinish - thing is, this is how I distinguish the selected sign from the other signs on offer (by altering its class). All sign options use the same classes/Id's for form elements to do price lookups against an array based on the options selected - I would not want to change this. How can I specifically select "signs selected_sign"? Do I need to add an ID to it and select it that way?

Comment: Try `$(".signs.selected_sign #s2FaceFinish")`  http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/kwqoyt0j/4/ . Without leading `.` , not valid selector - unless create `selected_sign` tag / element